# Flag modal duplicates the duplicate option

Tags: support, feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions

So this has been on my mind for quite a few days now, and I can't seem to figure out how this is a thing, and what the thought process behind this is.

I enjoy going around Stack Overflow flagging posts to make the community better. After some time I started noticing that there are multiple ways of marking a duplicate question.

As you can see this is the first modal that opens up when you click the *flag* button.

[image: The flag modal that pops up when the clicking *flag* link]

As you see the 4th option is **a duplicate...**, and can be used to mark a question as such.

Let's take a look at the description of **should be closed...**:

> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/), and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.

If you click on **should be closed...** a new modal dialog opens:

[image: Modal dialog that opens when clicking **should be closed...** in the first modal]

As you can read, all of the options match the description of what **should be closed...** is about ... except for the **duplicate of...** option.

So, what is the exact thought process behind the 2 duplicate options in this flagging system? And why is it not in the description of the **should be closed...** option?

This greatly confuses flaggers.

- If this is *not* a mistake, what is the rationale behind duplicating the option?
- If this *is* a mistake, can we change this?

Comment: So the option to close as duplicate, is itself in duplicate. I say it's an Easter Egg :-)

Comment: Which new _feature_ are you exactly requesting here?

Comment: @TheDude As I read it, the request is to have only one "close as duplicate". Or to adjust the text in the first modal dialog, as an alternative.

Comment: @TheDude the request is to either include a description for duplicate question in the second window after clicking should be closed, or removing the option duplicate from the should be closed window

Comment: @S.L.Barth I see ...

Comment: I greatly improved the post by adding [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775). Also changed other minor things - feel free to revert, @Tomm.

Comment: @Justastudent no need to revert, only made the post better gj!

Comment: A duplicate about duplication of duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a mistake. When you earn 3k reputation and get the privilege to close, you get a "close" link next to the "flag" link which allows you to vote to close a question, which is the one 3k users usually use to vote to close questions, including as duplicates:

[image]

This flag brings up a list of reasons for why the question should be closed, which is exactly the same as the Flag -> Should be closed dialog except that it allows you to vote to close directly instead of just flagging:

[image]

The "duplicate" option is there because closing as duplicates works just like closing questions that don't belong on the site: it takes 5 users to close a question as a duplicate, 5 users to reopen it, and you can't post answers to duplicates.

Since the Flag -> Should be closed dialog is just a copy of the Close dialog, it contains exactly the same options, which is why "duplicate" is one of them. I would guess that that the Flag -> Should be closed dialog for <3k users and the Close dialog for >3k users use the same code. I don't know how difficult it would be to write new code to omit the duplicate option from the Should be closed dialog, but probably difficult enough that they didn't think it would be worth it.

I would guess that the duplicate option is also present directly in the flag dialog to make flagging as a duplicate more intuitive because as you say, duplicates don't match the description of "should be closed", so that option could be difficult to find for new users otherwise.

And for the description of "should be closed", the duplicate option is already there in the same dialog so there isn't really any need to make it include the duplicate reason.

So the "duplicate" option is actually a part of "should be closed", but there is a shortcut to it directly in the flag dialog to make it easier to find.

Comment: Why wont they make it so only above 3k users see it then? Cause this still brings alot of confusion

Comment: @Tomm As I said, I don't think they thought it was worth changing the code just for that. You would have to ask a Stack Exchange developer to know exactly how difficult it would be to change it, but it's probably more difficult than it's worth it.

Comment: @Tomm I don't see how this brings confusion, it's just two ways to do the same thing, and both are clearly labeled with what they do.

Comment: @DavyM In Python language speaking: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." (The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters)

Comment: @Colidryre And... Your point? Regardless of Tim's explanations on how Python is meant to be very straightforward, that doesn't mean that there can't exist two ways of doing the exactly same thing. If I'm going to print the last element of a list, I can use list slicing with an index of -1, or index of the list length minus one, or iterate over the list and work with the last entry... All of which might have their own time and place, depending on what else is going on in the code, and each is valid in certain ways. Having several documented ways to do something is often useful, not confusing.